# Why am I getting CssSyntaxError: <css input> from PostCSS build?

Tags: next.js, postcss, google-fonts

I am doing what I *think* is a standard Next.js build.  It works fine in development mode but when I try to get a production build, I get:

```
(node:39333) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CssSyntaxError: <css input>:17:20: Missed semicolon
at Input.error (/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:129:16)
```

But here is the strange things: *I don’t have any CSS.*

Actually, I had some CSS but I deleted it all to figure out what was going wrong.  No change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After an hour or so of frustration, I did what I should have done in the first 10 minutes, and edited the file `postcss/lib/input.js` to just print out the offending CSS, and got quite a surprise.  Let me describe the sequence of events in the order they occurred, not the order I discovered them.

A few days ago, I received from the designer an HTML file with the layout she wanted.  In the `<head>`, there were some `<link>`s to the fonts she had chosen, including:

```
<link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=FontAwesome"
        rel="stylesheet"
  />
```

What I didn’t noticed (apparently the designer didn’t either) was that there is no such font-family (FontAwesome is the name of font *toolkit*), I dutifully copied the line into my React code.  Next.js and the browser plowed right through the problem.

PostCSS did not.  Instead, when attempting the production build, it tried to parse *the error page* that Google sent.

Unfortunately, the error page was, you know, just an error page.  Nobody at Google had scrutinized it for strict standards-compliance.  Sure enough, near the top I found:

```
     body {
       background: 100% 5px no-repeat;
       margin-top: 0;
       max-width: none:
```

That colon there at the end is supposed to be a semi-colon.  Of course, removing the useless link to the nonexistent font solved the problem.

Now I don’t know who to blame:

- Google for having a syntax error on an error page
- Google for not running a check on their error pages
- Google for returning a 400 instead of a 404 when it cannot find a font
- PostCSS for trying to parse an error page (I don’t know if the 400/404 thing confused it, but still)
- PostCSS for giving such an obscure error message
- the designer for giving me a link to a bad font

Because, you *know* I am not blaming myself...

Answer (score 5):

For people who couldn't still understand the issue or find out where's the mistake, check for any links like

```
<link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
```

Please make sure your weights are in **ascending order** or else it will throw **400** error from google and still show the same error from PostCSS

Answer (score 2):

Following code solved my problem.

**Pre:**

```
                    <link
                        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monserat:wght@300;400;500;900&display=swap"
                        rel="stylesheet"
                    />
```

**Post:**

```
                    <link
                        href={`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monserat:wght@300;400;500;900&display=swap`}
                        rel="stylesheet"
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Next.js app:

```
<Head>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Petrona"
        rel="stylesheet"
    />
</Head>
```

Note that the only difference between your code and mine is: **css2**

Comment: The error page for `css2` seems to have the same problem.